# How to build a project with an icon by `cabal build` or `stack build`

Tags: haskell, icons

I want to build an executable with an icon. By googling it, I find [the instruction here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Setting_an_executable_icon), but it only works by compiling a source file with `ghc`.

If I want to build a project with an executable by `cabal build` or `stack build`, how should I configure the `.cabal` or `.yaml` files such that `cabal build` or `stack build` can directly create an executable with an icon?

I've googled it for a while, but nothing useful.

I appreciate it if any tips are given.

Comment: What if you include `"$targets": Icon.o` in the `ghc-options:`?

Comment: Thanks! That works although there is a warning telling "the following files would be used as linker inputs, but linking is not being done: Icon.o"

Answer (score 2):

According to @Willem Van Onsem's suggestion, the following is the solution:

- for a `stack` project, add the following configure into the `stack.yaml` file

```
    ghc-options:

        "$targets": Icon.o
```

- for a `cabal` project, add the following `ghc-options` into the `.cabal` file

```
    ghc-options:

        Icon.o
```

Comment: I have problem creating the Icon.o file. Winres give me syntax error. My post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095586/syntax-error-when-running-winres-trying-to-set-executable-icon